# C++ Pass by references?

Tags: c++, data-structures, linked-list

I'm getting some errors that I'm not sure how to fix. It seems like I'm having trouble correctly passing my parameters to a class member function in List.h. How can I fix this? CONSTRAINTS: I can't modify the parameters or return type of is_equal.

```
Demo.cpp:60:38: error: no matching function for call to ‘List<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> >::is_equal(List<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> >*&)’
bool random = list2->is_equal(list3);
                                  ^
In file included from Demo.cpp:1:
List.h:339:8: note: candidate: ‘bool List<T>::is_equal(const List<T>&) const [with T = std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>]’
bool is_equal(const List<T> &other) const
    ^~~~~~~~
List.h:339:8: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘List<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> >*’ to ‘const List<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> >&’
```

My code to call is_equal in Demo.cpp:

```
List<string> *list2 = new List<string>();
List<string> *list3 = new List<string>();

// code to add values to list2 and list3

bool random = list2->is_equal(list3);    // line 60
```

The is_equal function in List.h:

```
/**
 *   description:  returns true if calling List and parameter
 *      List other contain exactly the same sequence of values.
 *      Returns false otherwise.
 *
 *  REQUIRMENT:  Linear runtime (O(n) where n is MIN(len1,len2)
 *    and len1 and len2 are the respective lengths of the two lists.
 **/
bool is_equal(const List<T> &other) const    // line 339
  {
    Node *p = front;
    int pLength = 0;
    int otherLength = 0;
    while (p != nullptr) {
      pLen++;
      p = p->next;
    }
    while (other != nullptr) {
      otherLen++;
      other = other->next;
    }
    if (pLen == otherLen)
      return true;
    return false;
  }
```

Answer (score 3):

You are trying to pass a `List *` pointer where a `const List &` reference is expected.  Simply dereference the pointer to access the object being pointed at, so the reference can bind to that object:

```
bool random = list2->is_equal(*list3);
```

Otherwise, don't use `new` to allocate the `List` objects dynamically in the first place:

```
List<string> list2;
List<string> list3;
...
bool random = list2.is_equal(list3);
```

Comment: Thanks for the fast response. I had already tried the first suggestion, but that resulted in about two screen's worth of errors. Trying your second suggestion gave me the same results.

Comment: @leo_s [Works fine for me](https://ideone.com/QePOsc).  So you are clearly doing something different in your real code that what you have shown here.

Comment: That can't be because I copied and pasted all the code and errors exactly as they appear. I guess that means it's an issue with the machine I'm running it on and not the code itself. Thanks for helping me figure that out.

Comment: @leo_s No, it most likely means there's an error somewhere in a part of the code you haven't shown us.

Comment: @leo_s What I have given you is accurate for what you have shown so far, so if you are getting more errors, they have to be in other code you haven't shown yet. Please update your question to provide a [mcve] (emphasis on **complete**) that demonstrates the errors in action, and provide the other errors you are seeing.